# Probability with a die and 52 card deck

Tags: probability

A fair die is rolled and a card is chosen at random from a $52$ cards deck

What is the probability that "a multiple of 3 appears and a card with ace or king is chosen" ?

My turn

$\frac{2}{6} \times \frac{8}{52}\times 2$
Is this correct? Or we would not multiply by 2 ?

Comment: What's the theory behind multiplying by $2$?

Comment: Switching between the outcome of the die and the cards , @lulu

Comment: The multiplying by 2 happens when the order of the events is not relevant.  This requires that the events be identical. Dice and cards are not identical.

Comment: Thank you , this so helpfull@DougM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to multiply by 2. Anytime you are finding the probability of simple compound events you just need to multiply the probability of each event. Hope that helps! :)